# How to efficiently join these 3 tables?

Tags: database, postgresql, inner-join, relationship

I am developing a personal agenda that has 4 tables in the database. How do I get the contacts that correspond to the user and the addresses and phones corresponding to that user's contact?

follow the
[diagram ER.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3jmPh.png)

I'm not very experienced yet and I never developed a real system I don't know if this relationship structure is correct. If you have something that helps to improve or correct this structure I would appreciate it.

NOTE: I am using PostgreSql

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Because of PG SQL engine has no clustered indexes nor Index Organized Table, There is not more efficiency to add a "super key" instaed of creating the PRIMARY KEY with the three FK columns. So drop your extra PK and make the three FK columns the PK.

Comment: Thus [diagram ?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J0guZ.png)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
SELECT  *

FROM    contacts
    JOIN user ON contacts.id_user = user.id
    JOIN addres ON contacts.id_addres = addres.id
    JOIN phones ON contacts.id_phone = phone.id
```

Maybe you want a LEFT JOIN, but that depends on your data and requirements. And of course you replace the * with the names of the columns that you need.

Answer (score 0):

Based on this [diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J0guZ.png) that I did based on the @SQLpro explanation this is the resolution of my problem:

```
SELECT * FROM contacts 
         INNER JOIN user ON contacts.id_user = user.id
         INNER JOIN addres ON adresses.id_contact = contacts.id
         INNER JOIN phones ON phones.id_contact = contacts.id
```

This sql returns the addresses and telephones associated with the contact that is ultimately associated with the user.